# TextView text shrink to the given width

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview field in my activity. Its font size is 16. 
Its text is set through code. Suppose if I am having a big text, it should shrink this data (i.e. font size reduces) instead of going to the next line. How can I do it?

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_width="400dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="" android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got it by using the following method which I created according to my requirement.

```
private void autoScaleTextViewTextToHeight(TextView tv)
    {
        String s = tv.getText().toString();
        float currentWidth = tv.getPaint().measureText(s);

        float phoneDensity = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        while(currentWidth > (REQUIRED_WIDTH * phoneDensity)) {         
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, tv.getTextSize() - 1.0f); 
            currentWidth = tv.getPaint().measureText(s);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Following method takes the TextView as parameter and adjust the size of its font according to the width of the given TextView

```
private void adjustTextSize(TextView tv) {

    float size = tv.getPaint().getTextSize();
    TextPaint textPaint = tv.getPaint();
    float stringWidth = textPaint.measureText(tv.getText().toString());
    int textViewWidth = tv.getWidth();
    if(textViewWidth > stringWidth) {

        float percent = (textViewWidth / stringWidth);
        textPaint.setTextSize(size*percent);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

there is no nice way.  what you can do is calc the size of the text you are about to place in this TextView, and re-adjust your font size until it fits in target area.  to calc size use Paint.getTextBounds().

I have done very similar for drawing on a canvas.  requries a loop that decreases the fontsize until the calc-ed size is suitable.