# Android Text not fitting into the List

Tags: android

I make a simple list choice multiple selection option, using an array of String. The text of the list item is very long and wrapped into 2-5 lines. The text is not being fit into the list item boundary if it exids more than 2 rows. The **boundary of the List item overlapping the text**.

Please let me know how to adjust the height of the List item accoding to the lenght of the text.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to cut off the text if its very long or wrap everything by adjusting the font?
If you need to adjust with the font you may look into the following question, which I faced and the answer is written by me itself in it...

[TextView text shrink to the given width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150480/textview-text-shrink-to-the-given-width)

Comment: But I am using the Android list, cant access the testView of the list object.